# Replace specific table values using a Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, html, dom, greasemonkey

This is the first table on the page by the way. I want to be able to change the value of the `td` elements by referencing their position.

So, if I could state the 3rd `td` element in a specific `table>tr` pathway that would be great. And then to replace the text value. The text itself repeats a lot so I can't do a search for specific text values.

Also some of the td values are blank `<td> </td>`. And I would like to replace the blank table values as well. The `tr` class names are identical.

```
<table><tbody>
<tr class="table-header"><td colspan="4"><h3>First</h3></td></tr>

<tr class="table-header">
    <th class="col">Number</th>
    <th class="col">Name</th>
    <th class="col">Quantity</th>
    <th class="col">Type</th>
</tr>
<tr class="left-bottom-border">
    <td>element 1</td>
    <td>element3</td>
    <td>element2</td>
    <td>element3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="left-bottom-border">
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
</tr>
<tr class="left-bottom-border">
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>blank</td>
</tr>
<tr class="left-bottom-border">
    <td>I don't</td>
    <td>think this matters</td>
    <td>but I'm going to replace</td>
    <td>all of the data</td>
</tr>

<tr class="table-header"><td colspan="4"><h3>Second Table</h3></td></tr>
<tr class="table-header">
    <th class="col">Number</th>
    <th class="col">Name</th>
    <th class="col">Quantity</th>
    <th class="col">Type</th>
</tr>
<tr class="left-bottom-border">
    <td>More</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr class="left-bottom-border">
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>

<tr class="table-header"><td colspan="4"><h3>Third Table</h3></td></tr>
<tr class="table-header">
    <th class="col">Number</th>
    <th class="col">Name</th>
    <th class="col">Quantity</th>
    <th class="col">Type</th>
</tr>
<tr class="left-bottom-border">
    <td>element 1</td>
    <td>element3</td>
    <td>element2</td>
    <td>element3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="left-bottom-border">
    <td>so more elements</td>
    <td>yada</td>
    <td>yada</td>
    <td>ya</td>
</tr>
<tr class="left-bottom-border">
    <td>x</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>z</td>
    <td>aa</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Not sure where you get stuck. Do you know how, in Javascript, to get an array of table cells from a table (if you have the table)?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`document.querySelector()`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to get the table, then use the [`.rows`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6156016) and [`.cells`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-67349879) properties to get a particular `<td>` (or `<th>`) cell.

For example, for the code shown in the question, this will change the third row, first column ("element 1"):

```
var fstTable    = document.querySelector ("body > table:nth-of-type(1)");

fstTable.rows[2].cells[0].textContent = "*changed*";
```

You can [**see this code in action at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JRXHH/1/).

---

**To find and replace blank cells**, you *could* use the `:empty` selector with `querySelectorAll` -- except that this works poorly in practice due to stray whitespace.

The more robust alternative is to actually check the content of the cells. Like so:

```
var fstTable    = document.querySelector ("body > table:nth-of-type(1)");
/*-- This only works when there is no stray whitespace:
var emptyCells  = fstTable.querySelectorAll ("td:empty");
*/
var emptyCells  = fstTable.querySelectorAll ("td");

for (var J = emptyCells.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    if (emptyCells[J].textContent.trim () == "") {
        emptyCells[J].textContent = "*was blank*";
    }
}
```

`.trim()` removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

this javascript code let's you replace the content of a TD by it's index where 0 is the first element.

```
var tbl=document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]; //get the first TABLE

var trs=tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr'); //get all TR's in that table 

var replaceTD=function(TRindex,TDindex,value){
 trs[TRindex].getElementsByTagName('td')[TDindex].innerHTML=value; // replaced with innerText
};
```

to change the second TD of the first TR that is not a title (so the third)

your indexes will be TRindex=2 cause it starts from 0 ...

and the TDindex=1

and the function you will call is :

```
replaceTD(2,1,'WHATEVER');
```

Comment: `innerText` is not a valid property.

Comment: innerHTML, nodeValue, textContent ... innerText works also. and it's prolly more supported than querySelector

Comment: trim & querySelector is also not supported by IE older than 9, innerText does not work in firefox

Comment: This is a ***Greasemonkey*** question.  That means the browser is Firefox, unless otherwise stated (mis-tagged), and IE does not apply.